# I am trying to identify suspicious content within a PDF file

Tags: malware, email, pdf

I have a PDF file that has been sent to me as part of a suspicious email.  I viewed the email as message source from within outlook.  This  gave me all raw text within the email.  I copied this to Visual Studio Code.  I know the email is suspicious because of the sender ID etc.

There is a PDF file attached to the email that I have not opened but I want to view the source of the PDF for suspicious activity.  As part of my own security education, can anyone please tell me:

1. How to view the raw content of the PDF, there are hundreds of lines of random text after:
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=CaseAMAZONID-XXXXXXXXXX.pdf
2. Is this the content of the PDF?
3. How can I identify suspicious activity/content within the PDF, assuming these hundreds of lines are in fact the PDF attachment?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to analyse the raw code or do you want to confirm that it is malicious? You could simply open it in a malware sandbox, like cuckoo.ee to see "what happens".

Comment: Thank you, will give this a try